# unable to upgrade to ruby 3.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, ubuntu-21.04

[image]

[image]

I am trying to upgrade ruby version 3.1.2 I am getting this error and when it says to install messing dependencies I get the error unable to locate the package now my ruby version is 2.7.4 and I installed using rbenv, and I use Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: It's not updating, I think needs to be upgraded to Ubuntu 22 but i don't have time for that

Comment: According to this documentation, installing ruby `3.1.2` on `Ubuntu 21.10` should be possible: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/21.10

Comment: There are additional steps explained on that page you could try, however, I can't advise much further than that without more information, e.g. what do you mean by "it's not updating"?

Comment: it means i tried to run that command but it is not working  and gives other errors

Comment: And what are the "other errors"? If you'd like assistance in resolving a problem, please try to provide all useful information upfront.

Comment: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A8580BDC82D3DC6C
Hit:7 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                
Ign:8 http://af.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                   
Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release                                
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Ign:10 http://af.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease

Comment: The above comment has some of the errors

Comment: ok i tried to add them but this comment section has character limitation i add them now

Comment: Hit:11 https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/impish pgadmin4 InRelease
Ign:12 http://af.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease
Err:13 http://af.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]

Comment: Err:14 http://af.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:15 http://af.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]

Comment: @TomLord Thank you for helping me I did some search on it I think I need to upgrade Ubuntu to versin 22 which i don't wish to do it what you think is it possible to fix withut upgrading?

Comment: I googled your error on "public key not available", and this is the top result: https://askubuntu.com/a/15272 ---- I don't think you need to upgrade ubuntu, I think you need to successfully run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Ok, I look at the link you provided and try to be able to run successfully apt-get update

Comment: I could fix the command sudo apt-get update by changing /etc/apt/sources.list so archive.ubuntu.com and security.ubuntu.com are changed to old-releases.ubuntu.com. This allows me to update/upgrade from an EOL version (e.g. Impish). Better instructions can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades wen i run rbenv install 3.1.2 I get the same error in the first screenshot above ( please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby)

Comment: Ubuntu 21 isn't even close to EOL... Heck, Ubuntu 16 doesn't reach EOL until 2026! And again, I'l emphasise: I do not think you need to upgrade from ubuntu 21 to ubuntu 22. You can if you want, but I don't think it's a blocker. The problem is that you need to install `libreadline-dev`, and to do that you probably need to fist `apt-get update`.

Comment: I've upgraded to Ubuntu 22 when I run rbenv install 3.1.2 I get this ERROR: Ruby installation aborted due to missing extensions
Try running `apt-get install -y libssl-dev libyaml-dev` to fetch missing dependencies. And also now when I run apt-get update no error I get.

Comment: ...And did you run `apt-get install -y libssl-dev libyaml-dev`?

Comment: Yes i did and everything seems fine. sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev libyaml-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libyaml-dev is already the newest version (0.2.2-1build2).
libssl-dev is already the newest version (3.0.2-0ubuntu1.6).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libc-ares2 libnode72
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: The ruby installation error says you need to install `libssl-dev`, but you already have `libssl-dev` installed? And there is *no other error* when trying to install ruby? Does it suggest reading an error log file? Did you read it?

Comment: Yes I read that one was saying yaml extesion is missing I could Fix this problem with https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-ruby-on-rails/ this it was actually weird first  did not work then I just downloaded openssl1.1.1 manually and did not touch it or compile it and tried agian it worked

Comment: now I have ruby version 3.1.2 but when i want to deploy to heroku it is saying your ruby version is 2.7.4